# headsepline from KOMA Script doesn't show

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

After reading the official documentation I've tried to add a `headsepline` to a document but with much dismay so far.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, DIV=11, headings=small]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles  % Gets rid of the pagemark on the footer by resetting the pagestyle
                        % However, even without this the headsepline doesn't show
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lohead*{Author1, Author2}
\cohead*{Title}
\rohead*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

TEST

\chapter{Two}

Tests

\end{document}
```

Is there another option I forgot to add to make this work? I am using XeTeX btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter pages uses pagestyle `plain` by default. You have to add option `plainheadsepline`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, DIV=11, headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline,
  plainheadsepline% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead*{Author1, Author2}% or \ihead{...}
\cohead*{Title}% or \chead{...}
\rohead*{\pagemark}% or \ohead{...}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
TEST
\chapter{Two}
Tests
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! Learned something new and solved the problem, thanks!